Finding Chrome active application or Window from Linux
ChromeOS runs Linux as Debian VM (also known as Crostini) and can run PWAs and Android applications.
On ChromeOS, I have a requirement that from a Linux applicaton, I want to find which Window is under use by the user across ChromeOS. This means active window can be a Linux app or PWA or Android app.
Is it possible to get the active window from with in Linux for entire ChromeOS?
I tried to fire commands on Linux to determine active window but it seems to return active window from with in Linux only and ignores PWAs and Android apps.

I don't think you can get parent information from a Linux container.
